# PFQueryTableViewController sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a PFQueryTableViewController and I want to add sections to the tableview, I try it like this:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

  // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
  // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
  if (self.objects.count == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
  }

  [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

  return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                       object:(PFObject *)object {
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Challenge";
  PFTableViewCell* cell;


  if (indexPath.section == 0)
  {
      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      if (!cell)
      {
          cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      }
      cell.textLabel.text = @"Test section 1";
  }

  if (indexPath.section == 1) 
  {
      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      if (!cell)
      {
          cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      }
      cell.textLabel.text = @"Test section 2";
  }

  return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
      NSInteger rows = 0;

      if (section == 0)
      {
          rows = 1;
      }
      if (section == 1)
      {
          rows = [self.objects count];
      }

      return rows;
  }
```

But I always get this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: 
index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

I know what it means but don't see why. When I change `rows = [self.objects count]`, for section = 0, it works.

Thanks for your help

EDIT: call stack:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b085e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0288b8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02aa9556 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 246
    3   Challenger                          0x0003e573 -[PFQueryTableViewController objectAtIndexPath:] + 69
    4   Challenger                          0x0003e77e -[PFQueryTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 184
    5   UIKit                               0x016ecd2f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
    6   UIKit                               0x016ece03 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
    7   UIKit                               0x016d1124 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2378
    8   UIKit                               0x016e45a5 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
    9   UIKit                               0x01668dd7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0289d81f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    11  QuartzCore                          0x00a3b72a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00a2f514 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    13  QuartzCore                          0x00a2f380 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    14  QuartzCore                          0x00997156 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    15  QuartzCore                          0x009984e1 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00998bb4 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x02ad053e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 30
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x02ad048f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x02aae3b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x02aadb33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x02aad94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0356e9d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x0356e7fe GSEventRun + 104
    24  UIKit                               0x015fe94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    25  Challenger                          0x0000967d main + 141
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0481870d start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: What is the exception stack trace?

Comment: The exception says that the array is empty. Which line is causing the exception?

Comment: This code looks fine. I suspect that the exception was raised at another point. Please post the exception log.

Comment: Does the query not return sections? Why are you hard coding the first section to include only 1 row? Is your goal to show a kind of "static" cell in the first section, and then the query result rows in the second section?

Comment: Yes Marius thats exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to override `- (PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
- (PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PFObject *obj = nil;
    if (indexPath.row < self.objects.count)
    {
        obj = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: How does this add sections to a PFQTVC?